# Difference between the Shiva Purana and the Linga Purana

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, translation-request, linga-purana

Both the Shiva Purana and the Linga Purana are books on Lord Shiva. I have read Shiva Purana. Can somebody please explain what is extra or differently told in the Linga Purana? Also, if possible please add a link of verse by verse English translation of the Linga Purana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the Shiva Purana and the Linga Purana is analogous to the difference between the Vishnu Purana and the Srimad Bhagavatam; the Vishnu Purana is an older work, focusing on Vishnu in general rather than Krishna in particular, whereas the Srimad Bhagavatam puts more emphasis on Krishna, although it still recounts Vishnu stories unconnected to Krishna.  Similarly, the Shiva Purana is a work dealing with Shiva in general.  It was composed by the sage Parashara, Vyasa's father, and it was condensed by Vyasa into a much shorter work, with some or all of the removed parts put into the Vayu Purana.  The Linga Purana, on the other hand, was composed later and puts more emphasis on Shiva's Linga form, how to worship a Shiva Linga, etc., although it still recounts stories of Shiva unconnected to the Shiva Linga.

As far as I know, the only unabridged translation of the Linga Purana is the two-volume translation published by Motilal Banarsidass.  Here are links to the two volumes in PDF format:

- [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20660)
- [Volume 2](http://gdurl.com/JgM2)

Volume 1 is on DSpace, the digital repository of the West Bengal Public Library Network.  I found Volume 2 on the [Digital Library of India](http://www.dli.ernet.in), and then I downloaded it as a PDF file using the program DLI downloader, and I uploaded it to Google Drive.

Comment: @Aby You're welcome.  I suggest you also use that program DLI Downloader I mentioned.  You may find lots of good books.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the book. I will read the book & would see whether you believe everything written there in the book or not. :) or you turn out to be selective there as well?

Comment: @Rohit. No, I don't endorse everything in the book.  Note where I say "This leads some people to believe..."

Comment: The  Video  ( 6min 14s - 6min 16s )  [Craig ][4] makes contemporary references about Linga Purana predictions:

  [4]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUFQZ2PXm0o