# What is the story of Siva's Incarnation (ईशान) Ishan?

Tags: shiva, puranas, avatars, shiva-purana

According to what I have studied yet the 23rd incarnation of **Lord Shiva** is (ईशान) Ishan (**The ruler**).
The story related to this incarnation is not described much deeper or it can be my fault that I have not found a good reference yet. Can anybody help me with brief story to clear my doubts.

Comment: What do you mean by 23rd incarnation?  What list of incarnations are you referring to?

Comment: I have read something about the 23rd incarnation of Lord Shiva in a book but never read any story related with their 23rd incarnation "Ishan".

Comment: Well, Ishana does refer to one of the five aspects of Shiva, if that's what you're thinking of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishana

Comment: i has been read it well before, but i want a story related with Ishan(incarnation).

Comment: I also Herad a brief myth story, they birth with "Maa Saraswati" And Their height was 5,11 then.

Comment: What do you mean "they birth with Maa Saraswati"?  Are you saying that Ishana was born at the same time as Saraswati?

Comment: yea but it's a myth.Therefor i want to know the true story.

Comment: @Keshav - Yes, Siva and Saraswati were considered to be born together and are consider as brother and sister as per Brahma or brahmanda purana. Similarly, Lord Vishnu and Parvati are Brother and sister. Lord Bramha and Goddess Lakshmi are brother and sister as per one of these two puranas...As, far as Validity of it is concerned, i am not sure..This could be some kind of interpolation also.

Comment: @Krishna Vishnu and Parvati being called brother and sister has nothing to do with biological relations.  It has to do with a story where Parvati was doing some ritual (I forget the details, it might have been her wedding) where she needed a brother to help her complete it, so Vishnu stepped into that role.  In any case, here we're talking about some incarnation of Shiva named Ishana.

Comment: @EshanSingh : Is this Ishan related to ishanya kona (N-E corner) The most auspicous corner???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story of Shiva's incarnation **Ishana** is told in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/rqoR) from the Shatarudra Samhita of the Shiva Purana.  (You can read the Shiva Purana using the links in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3830/36).)  In this account, Brahma prays to Shiva in the Vishwarupa Kalpa, and as a result Saraswati manifests herself as his daughter Vishwarupa and Shuva manifests himself as his son **Ishana**. **Ishana** instructs Brahma, and then has four sons of his own:

> As Brahma, desirous of sons, meditated on Shiva mentally, Saraswati of great sound manifested herself.  She was Vishwarupa (Universe-formed).  **Ishana** of such renowned features, supreme lord of crystal-like pure brilliance and bedecked in all ornaments manifested himself.  On seeing **Ishana** the unborn lord, all pervading, all-bestowing, the all-in-all, of good forms as well as well as form, Brahma bowed to him.  Lord **Ishana** after instructing the path of the good to Brahma, created four auspicious sons in collaboration with his Energy.  They were born Jatin, Mundin, Sikhandin, and Ardhamunda.  By means of Yoga they imparted good virtue and attained the goal of Yoga.

I assume "goal of yoga" means Kaivalya liberation, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36).

The story is also told in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/0ZvH) from the Linga Purana.  (You can read the rest if the Linga Purana [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4142/36).)  This account provides more detail about the prayer that Brahma says as well as what **Ishana** teaches Brahma (it's about the fundamental nature of Saraswati).  It also provides the detail that Saraswati's incarnation Vishwarupa is a cow.

Comment: "in the Vishwarupa Kalpa" as in during the Vishwarupa Kalpa(age)?

Comment: @Naveen Yes, during the Vishwarupa Kalpa.  It was called the Vishwarupa Kalpa, because it was during that age that Saraswati's incarnation Vishwarupa was born.