# Multi headed or handed Gods in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, ramayana

I started reading a book called “Some aspects of Ramayan and Mahabharata” by Bibek Debroy.
(You can borrow it here https://archive.org/details/someaspectsofram0000debr/page/15/mode/1up)

First chapter of this book logically attempts to prove why Ravana couldn’t have been a rakshsha and possibility of him without ten heads and twenty hands.

Bibek provides verses from Valmiki Ramayan that shows inconsistencies in portraying Ravana sometimes as 2 handed / 1 head and sometime as 10 headed / 20 handed.

Considering that readers would justify these consistencies with Ravana ability of taking any form he wants (because of his rakshsha powers), Bibek further points out even if Ravana used to switch between these 2 forms, it doesn’t make sense that he would do so rapidly on same occasion. Example -

When Ravana came to abduct Sita, he assumed 20 handed 10 head form but when he tries to grasp Sita he uses 2 hand (Aranya kand , 49th Sarga, sloka 8-9) https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga49/aranya_49_frame.htm

> संरक्त नयनः श्रीमान् तप्त कांचन भूषणः | क्रोधेन महता आविष्टो नील जीमूत
>   सन्निभः || ३-४९-७ दश आस्यो विंशति भुजो बभूव क्षणदा चरः |
>
> वामेन सीताम् पद्माक्षीम् मूर्धजेषु करेण सः | ऊर्वोः तु दक्षिणेन एव
>   परिजग्राह पाणिना || ३-४९-१७

As you see switch between 2 form just doesn’t add up. Similarly when Fighting with Jatayu, Jatayu cuts Ravana’s 20 hands and immediately in next verse Ravana hits him with 2 hands.

Finally Bibek goes on to justify that 10 headed form could actually be mask that Ravana used to wear. He further states that multi form aspects of Rakshahs and gods (4 headed brahma) and personalities (like Sahastrabahu Arjun) were introduced in post Christian Era and influenced from Greek mythological creatures.

Personally to me this goes against all the beliefs and conception that I have in our mythology and somewhere hurt the sentiments because then what is the truth?

**How does the other Hindu acharyas justify inconsistencies pointed out in Ramayan?
Are there scriptural references to multi headed or multi handed gods in Vedas?** (since Vedas are considered to be documented before Christian Era and if they have references to multi headed/handed gods then it should refute Bibek’s theory that Hindu multi headed gods were influenced from Greek mythology)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104640/discussion-on-question-by-ketan-multi-headed-or-handed-gods-in-vedas).

Answer (score 3):

Ravana's 10 heads is just metaphor - just like Purusha's "thousand heads" in the Purusha Sukta.

> Om sahasra shirsha purushaha
>   sahasrakshas sahasrapat"

1000 heads should imply 2000 eyes and 2000 feet - but the Purusha Sukta says "sahasra" for all - meaning that it is only a metaphor for infintude.

Comment: The Purusha Sukta isn't being metaphorical, it's using an Upalakshana or indication.  It is saying that he has a thousand heads as a way to indicate that he has at least a thousand heads.  But yes, what it ultimately means is that he has infinitely many heads, eyes, feet, etc.  If Ravana's case was analogous he would have at least ten heads.  Regardless Ravana has exactly ten heads, it's not a metaphor or Upalakshana.

Comment: Ravana is a person lust full desires which as 10 indriyas to be satisfied.. 5 gnan indriyas and 5 karameindriyas, cutting desire from these indiryas is cutting of ravanas head, ravana is us only humans..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That is what metaphorical means: "a thing regarded as representative or symbolic of something else, especially something abstract." The description of 1000 heads is not literal.

Comment: He does actually and literally have a thousand heads, it’s just that he doesn’t have only a thousand heads.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Another interpretation for 1000 heads is that Purusha is omniscient (since head is used for knowing).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The verse is saying that he has an infinite amount of heads by metaphorically (Upalakshana) saying that he has a thousand heads.

Comment: It is saying that he literally has a thousand heads.  What it is saying is literally true.  But it’s saying that he even has a thousand heads, it’s not putting a limit on the number of his heads.  Upalakshana is not metaphor.  Upalakshana is indicating the real attributes an object as an indication of what other attributes an object has. For indicate, when Sita tells Ravana “If you return me to Rama, he will be willing to accept you as a friend.” That is a true statement that indicates Rama’s compassion, but does not exhaust his compassion. He’d also be willing to accept Ravana in other roles.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok I see

Answer (score 3):

I realized that my previous answer was incorrect as I had overlooked other verses. So I have deleted it. 
It does look that Ravana only had two hands but he was ten-faced.

From [Valmiki Ramayan, Aranya Kanda Sarga 51](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga51/aranya_51_frame.htm)

> ततः क्रोद्धात् दशग्रीवः सीताम् उत्सृज्य वीर्यवान् |
>
> मुष्टिभ्याम् चरणाभ्याम् च गृध्र राजम् अपोथयत् || ३-५१-४०
>
> The valorous Decahedron Ravana then threw off Seetha, and out of fury he scuffled with the king of eagles with fisticuffs and kicks, by both his feet and fists. [3-51-40]

Here it is absolutely clear that Ravana was using two hands and two feet. The words मुष्टिभ्याम् and चरणाभ्याम् as per Sanskrit declension refer to two fists/hands and two legs.

The above does not make sense if in Sarga 49 he had 20 arms.

> संरक्त नयनः श्रीमान् तप्त कांचन भूषणः |
>
> क्रोधेन महता आविष्टो नील जीमूत सन्निभः || ३-४९-७
>
> दश आस्यो विंशति भुजो बभूव क्षणदा चरः |
>
> That celebrated Ravana whose eyes are bloodshot as he is ensorcelled by desperate fury transmuted his form into a tend-faced, twenty-armed night-walker wearing golden ornaments of purified gold and appearing as a black tempestuous cloud. [3-49-7, 8a]

Turns out other versions of Valmiki Ramayana has this verse mentioned somewhat differently

From [Valmiki Ramayana commentarty by Bhusana](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/commentaries?language=dv&field_commnetary_tid=14&field_kanda_tid=3&field_sarga_value=49)

> संरक्तनयनः श्रीमांस्तप्तकाञ्चनकुण्डलः ।
>
> क्रोधेन महताविष्टो नीलजीमूतसन्निभः ।
>
> दशास्यः कार्मुकी बाणी बभूव क्षणदाचरः ।। 3.49.7 ।।
>
> Commentary
>
> संरक्तेति सार्धश्लोक एकान्वयः । श्रीमान् विचित्रशक्तिसम्पन्नः । क्षणदाचरः संरक्तनयनत्वादिविशिष्टो बभूव ।। 3.49.7 ।।

दशास्यः means "ten faced one", so not necessarily transformed into a being having 10 heads at that time. But we cannot rule out him not having ten heads.

Also विंशतिभुजः is replaced with कार्मुकी बाणी ~ holding a bow and arrow. So no mention of twenty arms.

The commentator is saying Ravana transformed into a form that had red eyes, and such features of a demon

This is the book in IITK's website

[[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4VtA.jpg)

And those who want to refer to CE, here is a screen shot from ORI Baroda 
[image]

They have removed the middle line completely and also mention that विंशतिभुजः is present in only two manuscripts.

Answer (score 3):

Both Rig to Yajur Vedās, Rudra's form is:

1. Viṣvarūpam, meaning the cosmic form or the all-encompassing
   omni-form.
2. Pururūpam, meaning multiform/multihued
3. Virūpam, meaning multifold altering forms
   [RV2.33.10,TS4.5.4,TA10.23.1.]

It was Mahābhāratam Itihasa 203 that actually gave a definition to the term Viṣvarūpam by saying

> “since those Devas called the Viṣvadevas are in Him, He is for that
> reason called Viṣvarūpam”.

Both Śrī Rudram and Śatarudrīya of Yajur Vedas describe a furious form emerging out of Prajāpati. This anger is called **Manyu**, the ferocious aspect of Rudra with a hundred heads, a thousand eyes, and thousands of weapons. This matches perfectly with Kausitaki Brāhmaṇa 6 of Rig Veda wherein it describes Rudra as a thousand-eyed and arms with thousand weapons.

This all-encompassing form of Rudra was very difficult to iconify into sculpture or painting, so two approaches are possible, the first option was to show one body with many heads and hands, like the magnificent sculpture at Thanumalayan Temple in Suchindram, Tamil Nadu. The latter option was to depict one being with various forms emerging out of it, like the Mahadeva Vishvaroopma icon found in Parel, Mumbai by the Indian Archeological Society, currently stored in Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj Vastu Sangrahalaya Museum.

After Nārāyaṇa Sukta and Śrīmad Bhagavādgita, Viṣṇu’s Viṣvarūpam took high prominence in its depiction. Alongside Rudra, Soma and Prajāpati shared the title of Viṣvarūpam, but Varuna is also addressed in a similar way RV7.34.
[For more details here is the article source](http://namahshivaya.net/appearance-of-rudra-visvarupam/)

[image: Sadasiva Vishvarupam,Thanumalayan Temple-Suchindram, Tamil Nadu]
[image: Mahadeva Vishwaroopam, 5th Century, Icon found in Mumbai, Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj Vastu Sangrahalaya. Indian Archeological Survey: AKS.9955, CC BY-SA 4.0]

Answer (score 2):

Hindu scriptures talk of spiritual truths through stories. One should not take every detail of these stories literally. Do the spiritual truths of Ramayana depend on whether Ravana had 10 heads or one head? Multiheaded Ravana or Multi handed Gods are metaphorical and should not be taken literally.

> Brahma tells Narada "This brief account of the manifestation of the
>   Lord is what is called the Bhagavata. The Supreme Being Himself gave
>   the knowledge of it to me. I have also given to you a brief account of
>   the Lord's glories and attributes. **You elucidate it with the help of
>   your imaginative power** in a way that will generate devotion in the
>   mind of men for Sri Hari who is the soul and support of all."

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana II.8.51-52**

> The Supreme Lord is said to be fond of such **figurative expositions of
>   spiritual truth through stories.** (For it is understandable even to
>   common men while an abstract philosophical statement can be understood
>   only by a very few.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.28.65**

> In times past I learnt **this wonderful allegory, which teaches the
>   truth of the Atman indirectly in a story form**.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.29.85**

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I have heard Bhagvatam before but never realise that it mentions that it’s stories are to be taken as allegory. But then where do we draw the boundaries? How much of it is fact and how much story? Can you add more pls

Comment: when you say “multi head Ravana or gods are metamorphical” , do you mean they (Ravana or gods) are metamorphical OR their multi head/hands aspect is metamorphical?

Comment: We don't know the amount of facts in our epics. I talked with a doctor who has just come back from Sri Lanka. He told me that he went to Ashok Vana where Sita was kept by Ravana and the place seemed to him to be special. He came back with the view that Ramayana must be describing some true facts but exactly how much is an open question.

Comment: I don't know about Ravana but the deities are not metaphorical. The deities exist and have been seen by many people. What is metaphorical is the way that the deities are depicted.

Comment: Thank you @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: 'He told me that he went to Ashok Vana where Sita was kept by Ravana and the place seemed to him to be special.' - According to H D Sankalia the original Ramayana took place in North and Central India. Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ5Yp.png) map for the location of the original Lanka, Kishkindha, etc.

Comment: Rama and his army had to cross an ocean to reach Lanka. Kishkindha has been identified as on the banks of Tungabhadra river opposite Hampi the capital of Vijayanagara empire. Bibek Debroy says in his introduction to Ramayana that incidents of Ramayana often occur along a north-south axis, called Dakshinapath. Sanjeev Sanyal in his book 'Land of the Seven Rivers' has made the point that the Dakshinapath during Rama's time was different from the subsequent Dakshinapath. Sankalia's view must be a minority view.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find mention of multi-headed and multi-handed Gods in the Rig Veda.   Bṛhaddevatā also did not mention about such issues.

1. The 5 faces of Sadasiva were explained [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20056/3869) (Taittariya Aranyaka).
2. The Thousand heads (सहस्रशीर्षा) and thousand legs of [Purusha](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10090.htm), the BRAHMAN ABSOLUTE, were mentioned in [RV X.90](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10090.htm).

The 1000 heads of Purusha or Brahman can be a metaphor only, as we cannot limit the viewing capacity of the Almighty to 1000 directions only.

---

There is no evidence to prove that the multi form Rakshahs and gods (4 headed brahma) and personalities (like Sahastrabahu Arjun) were introduced in post Christian Era influenced from Greek mythological creatures.

This can be conjecture of the author.

Those depictions might have been influenced by 5 faces of Sadasiva also.

Comment: 'There is no evidence to prove that the multi form ... were introduced in post Christian Era influenced from Greek mythological creatures.' - there is lot of evidence, check the [book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bw0j.png) OP has cited. The coincidences (building a bridge across the ocean, shooting an arrow at the ocean, etc.) are too many to ignore.

Comment: The OP didn't mention about bridge across the ocean, shooting an arrow at the ocean, etc.) in question part. Then how can I answer that part?  Indian authors also creative enough to introduce many new creative ideas. Arrows and Iron were mentioned even in Rig Veda.  Do you want to say even Rigveda was borrowed from Greek mythology? @sv.

Answer (score 1):

There are many such examples in both Shrutis and Smritis, Let me give one of them.:

**Sri Shiva Sankalpa Upanishad Mantra 2.:**

> *वि॒श्वत॑श्चक्षुरु॒त वि॒श्वतो॑मुखो वि॒श्वतो॑हस्त उ॒त वि॒श्वत॑स्पात् ।
> सं बा॒हुभ्यां॒ नम॑ति॒ सम्पत॑त्रै॒र्द्यावा॑पृथि॒वी ज॒नय॑न् दे॒व एक॒स्तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वस॑ङ्क॒ल्पम॑स्तु ॥*
>
> *He who hath eyes on all sides round about him, a mouth on all sides, arms and feet on all sides, He, the Sole God, producing earth and heaven, welded them, with his arms as wings, together; may my mind aspire towards Lord Śiva (or) Auspicious Śiva thoughts.*

**This was quoted by Srīkanṭha Śaivàcarya.:**

> *Even in the Siva-Sankalpa, He is declared to have faces on all sides. In the Atharvasiras, the Paramesvara is said to have many faces, feet, and so on. He is said to be associated with the universe as an integral part of His being.:*
>
> ***~ Śrīkanṭha Bhaṣya on Vedānata Sūtras, 3rd Adhyāya, 3rd Pada, 8th Adhikarana.***

I hope this clarifies your queries. Prd..

Comment: I only know about the following Shaiva Upanishads, to which Vedic Shaka does Shiva Sankalpa Upa belong to?
Kaivalya Upanishad, Atharvashiras, Atharvashikha, Brihajjabala, Kalagni Rudra, Dakshinamurti, Sharabha, Akshamalika, Rudrahridaya, Bhasmajabala, Rudrakshajabala, Pancabrahma Upanishad and Jabali Upanishad

Comment: Actually these are all hymns. But as they are so large people consider it as upanishad. More more u can see [this quora link](https://bhagwanshivamahadev.quora.com/%C5%9AR%C4%AA-%C5%9AIVA-SA%E1%B9%84KALPA-S%C5%AAKTAM), here it's properly mentioned in details that from which vaidik sākha which mantras belongs to. I hope this helps. ..

Comment: Bdw i wanted to tell you something from many days but i keep on forgetting even that Deshmukh convo's time also i forgot. I just remembered now so m gonna tell u.

Comment: In this [blog](https://namahshivaya.net/how-many-rudras/) of yours the Chandogya Up. Verse in Sanskrit verses you have given 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.9.1 and 6.9.2 but in English Translation you have given verses of 6.1.4, 6.2.1, 6.9.1 and 6.9.2. see, the clay verse is 6.1.4 and 6.2.2 is Aruni repeating the 6.2.1 verse again.

Comment: It just, it clicked me while reading it. That's it and nothing else. Cya. Tc.

Comment: Savdy ji. You are correct .. I will add 6.1.4 Sanskrit sloka to support the English commentary. Thank you very much, I would be really thankful if you can share more findings. Pranam

Comment: Sure when i get. ..