# Where is it mentioned about sister of Lord Shiva in religious texts?

Tags: shiva, parvati

I came across a page on internet that has a story of Lord Shiva's sister Devi Asavari. The article said that since Devi Parvati felt lonely on Mount Kailash being the only lady there, so she asked Lord Shiva to create a female companion or a sister-in-law for her. Lord Shiva obliged to that on the condition that Devi Parvati has to keep her female companion happy, to which Devi Parvati agreed. Thus, Lord Shiva created a lady similar to him in knowledge and powers who was later came to be known as Devi Asavari. Initially Devi Parvati was happy with her but later she disliked her for her heavy eating habits and rude nature.

The story is given on link :
https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.newsgram.com/know-why-goddess-parvati-asked-lord-shivas-sister-devi-asavari-to-leave-kailasha/&grqid=SaFe96JS&hl=en-IN

Can anyone please tell me whether is is an authentic story and taken from any puranas or other religious text or its just a folklore. Also, if there is any other story(s) or mention of her anywhere else, then please let me know the same.

Comment: The webpage says Shiva Purana has it. I checked complete Shiva Purana (text searchable) but didn't find it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Same was my doubt, I have also read Shiva Purana but never saw this story, thats why i was confirming which other book can have this.

Comment: It seems that there is a Hindustani Raga called Asavari, and there is a goddess of that Raga who is depicted as a Yogini in medieval artwork.  She may be the same as the Asavari described in that link.

Comment: Check this question for Shiva's sister though it is not the same as the one from your story: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/why-goddess-saraswati-is-considered-as-lord-shivas-younger-sister

Answer (score 1):

It is just a folk story. No basis in any vedic scripture. These days many webpages and many TV serials perpetuate folk stories and their own penned stories as scriptural stories.