# Is lord shiva superior to all the other deities?

Tags: shiva

Is there any scriptures which declare that lord shiva has all the powers that other deities (including the Shaktis) and he is superior to all in every aspect?
Though the glories of shiva is innumerable still can we highlight some points which gives him a superior status? Thank you.

Comment: Do these answer your question? - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57023/33936 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19831/33936

Comment: Superior status in doing what? What are the rules/qualification that makes one superior and the other inferior?

Comment: This type of questions are not allowed on this site. Please refer our policy.

Comment: I am very sorry @TheLittleNaruto , I just wanted to get some answers about the position shiva holds in every Puranik texts.