# Complete English translations of Puranas

Tags: scripture, puranas, translation-request, resource

Some English translations of Puranas can be found online here:

1. [Vishnu purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/index.htm)
2. (a) [Garuda purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/index.htm) (abridged)
3. (b) [Garuda purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt) (full)
4. [Bagavata Purana](http://bhagavata.org/)
5. (a) [Shiva Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3830/3500) (b) [Online proofread edition](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english)
6. [Linga purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4142/3500)
7. (a) [Brahmanda Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6751/3500) (b) [Online proofread edition](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana)
8. [Padma Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana)
9. [Narada Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4125/3500)
10. [Markandeya Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana)
11. [Brahma Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english)
12. [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana)
13. [Agni Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana)

(Correct me if any of these sources are abridged or not genuine)

What about unabridged versions of other Puranas? Are they available on net?

I found some Puranas on [DLI](http://www.dli.ernet.in/) but I don't know whether they are abridged or unabridged.

Can anyone mention online sources for complete English translations for other Puranas viz.:

- Brahmavaivartha Purana
- Kurma Purana
- Matsya purana
- Vamana purana
- Varaha Purana and
- Vayu Purana

If all these are not available, can anyone give sources for

- Matsya
- Vayu and
- Agni Puranas.

Comment: Though these are translations, it would be better if all the same are available in Sanskrit slogas too. Requesting the poster to add the same if possible as this could stand as a ready reckoner and for easy access.

Comment: You may download from Here: http://vedpuran.net/download-all-ved-and-puran-pdf-hindi-free/

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola are they unabridged versions? But they are in hindi.

Comment: yes they are in hindi but I found after posting link here ,

Comment: There is respectful disagreement amongst scholars that the bhagavata (one of the 18 puranas )refers to devi bhagavata vs bhagavata of srikrishna.

Comment: @moonstar2001 how were they classified?

Comment: "ma dwayam bha dwayam caiva bra trayam va catustayam ana pa linga ku skanicha" 

the names of 2 puranas start with ma (matsya,markandeya),2 with bha (bhavishya,bhagavata),3 with bra (brahmanda,brahma,brahma vaivarta),4 with va(vamana,varaha,Vishnu,vayu),
one each with a(agni),na(narada), pa(padma),ku(kurma),ska(skanda) & linga

Comment: @moonstar2001 thanks! Would you be kind to let me know the source of this śloka like — Who is the author behind it and from where it has been culled from i.e., was it from a purāṇa? from Patañjali MahāBhāṣya? or what?

Comment: YW @VinayaŚiṣya ! I do not know who the author of the sloka is. It is perhaps just a mnemonic devised for the convenience of scholars.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Note**: Skip to bottom of this answer to download complete Purana as single PDF file. All these puranas are scanned and non text searchable.

Index [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/skanda-purana-23-volumes-IDF415/) shows Skanda Purana consists 23 Volumes.Of 23 Volumes,20 volumes were found from [West Bengal Dspace.](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/browse?type=title)

> Skanda Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12961)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13010)
> 3. [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20835)
> 4. [Volume 4](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13009)
> 5. [Volume 5](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20756)
> 6. [Volume 6](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20761)
> 7. [Volume 7](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13008)
> 8. [Volume 8](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/22054)
> 9. [Volume 9](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21994)
> 10. [Volume 10](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13007)
> 11. [Volume 11](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13006)
> 12. [Volume 12](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/22009)
> 13. [Volume 13](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20764)
> 14. [Volume 14](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21050)
> 15. [Volume 15](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20778)
> 16. [Volume 16](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13005)
> 17. [Volume 17](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13004)
> 18. [Volume 18](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13003)
> 19. [Volume 19](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13002)
> 20. [Volume 20](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/13000)

I will update links for other Volumes after getting legitimate links.

Index [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/agni-purana-4-volumes-IDE887/) Shows Agni Purana consists four Volumes. I found all four volumes on West Bengal dspace.

> Agni Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12915)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12912)
> 3. [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12914)
> 4. [Volume 4](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/28710)

[This](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/brahma-purana-4-volumes-IDF030/) Index shows Brahma Purana consists four voulmes. Those Volumes were available on West Bengal Dspace.

> Brahma Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20566)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21097)
> 3. [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20588)
> 4. [Volume 4](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20270)

Kurma Purana was found in Two Volumes.Those Scanned Volumes were available on Dspace.

> Kurma purana.
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21487)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12944)

Index [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/vayu-purana-2-volumes-IDE900/) shows Vayu Purana consists two volumes. Those Volumes were found on West Bengal dspace.

> Vayu Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12977)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20638)

[Two](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/varaha-purana-2-volumes-IDF028/) Volumes of Varaha Purana were found on West Bengal dspace.

> Varaha Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12962)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12972)

Additionally, there's another version of Garuda Purana in three volumes on [exotic India](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/garuda-purana-3-volumes-IDE886/) and it's scanned copy was found on West Bengal Dspace.

> Garuda Purana
>
> 1. [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20541)
> 2. [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21508)
> 3. [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12942)

As [West Bengal Dspace](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/browse?type=title) goes dead frequently, I combined all Volumes of each Purana and Uploaded those single files  to Google drive as  PDFs.

> 1. [Agni Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHelp2dm9mdkVIOW8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-L8Hcj78wcLuwGxbWdr3ajQ) (83 MB)
> 2. [Bhagavata Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHbVFNdHMwUkg4UW8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-pzQ3YuK8prp_eI5XsL7Gvw) (151 MB)
> 3. [Brahmanda Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHS1htaTEyblE3WmM/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-kLFqI25Y5fszIPP6PonG3w) (126 MB)
> 4. [Garuda Puarana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHMW9vT2F3SU56SVE/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Hw6K2431rElwoJTVv-xmYg) (118 MB)
> 5. [Kurma Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHZ2d1aHEtVHNqMlU/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-js_1lrcpGWgwmzJcEtbnlg) (62 MB)
> 6. [Linga Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHSTI2SVNKejlic3c/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-tQmf_KhgStnCwt_zXVpZuw) (94 MB)
> 7. [Narada Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHLUFONHJmaXhBcDA/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-LbUbVYFJX8jRaq6gsXBuqg) (135 MB)
> 8. [Shiva Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHb3l2aEpSV0tmb28/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-XlzUrNRxc5WnKtfsQ9fPGw) (207 MB)
> 9. [Skanda Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHTTg3bzhHR3dlUGM/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-shqf1gaOFAG8aeUnXkf4tA) (502 MB)
> 10. [Varaha Pruna](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cYvGa-XIEzm_1B6LhPj2ZQZhNaPBRgTF/view?usp=sharing) (29 MB)
> 11. [Vayu Purana](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XpAgOLu_nHRVJPaUNhR3JqeWs/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-OiTgxY9Z8p7hxVy6fRuBig) (105 MB)

If you want to read Puranas in both Sanskrit and English, visit [Indianscriptures.com](http://indianscriptures.com). I have downloaded all of them and appended as single file but not posting any links here due to copyright uncertainities.

For more details visit [What is the copyright status of Indian books?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/332/3500)

Comment: Can you add narasimha purana as well?

Comment: @BhargavRao I think there is no Complete English translation of Narasimha Purana which is out of copyright.

Comment: It's good to see people reading whatever unauthorised copy they get, when all scriptures were burnt to ashes but bhagvad purana. God knows whether they spawn such copies from Doraemon's 4th dimensional pocket or something?

Comment: Matsya Purana

#1: https://archive.org/stream/Sacred_Books_of_the_Hindus/SBH%2017%20-%20Matsyapurana%20English%20Translation%20Part%201%20-%20Taluqdar%20of%20Oudh%201916#page/n1/mode/2up

#2: https://archive.org/stream/Sacred_Books_of_the_Hindus/SBH%2017%20-%20Matsyapurana%20English%20Translation%20Part%202%20-%20Taluqdar%20of%20Oudh%201917#page/n1/mode/2up

Are these two complete?

Comment: @thedestroyer I have sent an email regarding the pdfs you mention above.

Comment: Indiascriptures.com not finding both English and Sanskrit... The pdfs there are either Hindi, English translations. Are there any where can get Sanskrit text and enough translations?

Comment: *I have downloaded all of them and appended as single file but not posting any links here due to copyright uncertainities.* Can u please share it here?

Answer (score 15):

I found most of the Puranas on [www.indianscriptures.com](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana)

Most of them are in English.

I'm linking a screenshot to mark the ones in English so that it is easier to understand. The Agni Purana is with the green dot because it is in Hindi not English.

[image]

They haven't provided an index of the contents but most indexes would be available on Exotic India Art's Book Search, in the description.

As for copyright issues the site says it is fine to download for personal use.

Hope this was of some help.

Comment: Can you let me have Bhavisya MahaPuranam? Maybe you could upload it somewhere like google drive.
P.S: I'm hoping it's in English.

Comment: I've been looking for Bhavishya Purana too. However, the only complete version I found was [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/36307290/Bhavishya-Purana) and it's in Hindi.

Comment: thanks, the Hindi translation is still better than nothing. Just to highlight it for the readers here, since Scribd nowadays has some download restrictions, the same PDF can be availed at [Archive](https://archive.org/download/puran_bhavishya/Bhavishya.pdf) too.

Answer (score 5):

Over internet we usually get Hindi Puranas but there are some indian libraries where you can search for English translated version of Puranas like

http://www.dli.ernet.in/
http://cognise.quinki.com/

Answer (score 5):

About Narashima Purana

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOYw5SdaFyKsdeUIAmUEkW5em1AVxxk2/view

I hope this edition is good