# What is the story of Rishi Durvasa and King Ambarish?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

I want to know the story of Rishi Durvasa and King Ambarish. Please somebody answer my question!

Comment: See this blog http://hindumythologyforgennext.blogspot.in/2012/03/king-ambarish-and-sage-durvasa.html .

Answer (score 3):

King Ambarish ,a king of Surya Dynasty, was an ardent devotee of Lord Vishnu. Once King Ambarish decided to fast. But after few days he decided to break his fast as he was feeling hungry.Then Sage Atri and Anusuya's son Sage Durvasa appeared before him. Sage Atri suggested Ambarish to break his fast only when Sage Durvasa returned from bath. Ravenous Ambarsh could't wait for Durvasa and broke his fast by drinking water, at consent of other sages. But short-tempered Durvasa after knowing this, became angry and plucked a hair from his head and threw it on the ground. A demon sprouted from the hair and the demon killed the King Ambarish.

Lord Vishnu after knowing this got infuriated. Lord Vishnu sent his weapon Sudarshan Chakra to kill Sage durvasa.When Sudarshan Chakra was following him, Sage Durvasa pleaded to Ambarish's soul, which was wandering there. At the supplication of Ambarish's Soul , Lord Vishnu took back his Sudarshan Chakra without killing Sage Durvasa.

[image: Sage Duravasa followed by Sudarshana Chakra]

Comment: Sir, you should cite sources. You can refer this question (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas) for various puranas. Please update source.

Comment: @Goltu i dont think Ambrish was killed by Sage Durvasa. Can you please confirm.

Comment: Ambarisha was **not killed**. In fact it was Durvasa who was about to be killed, when he fell at Ambarisha's feet and was saved.

Comment: Besides, Vishnu couldn't do anything with Sudarshana, since he had gifted the chakra to Ambarisha.

Answer (score 1):

Apropos of above,Bhai Gurdass var 10(4) (Ambaris was not killed). When angry Rishi Durvasa realized that the king had not served him first, he ran to curse(Shraap)the king. On this , Lord Vishnu (to be known in the world as benevolent of devotees ) ordered his sudarshan chakra to move towards the rishi. Now brahmin Durvasa ran for his life but could not get shelter anywhere. Lastly he surrendered before Ambaris who saved the dying sage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).