# English translation of complete Garuda Purana

Tags: puranas, translation-request, garuda-purana

Where can I find English translation of complete Garuda Purana online?

Related question: [Complete English translations of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9078/2995)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Motilal Banarsidass translation of Garuda Purana by J.L. Shastri is an **unabridged** translation and can be downloaded using the link below or from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas/9095#9095).

[Garuda Purana English - Motilal - 3 Volumes in 1 (PDF, 120 MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dS6102zcBgNl9jdkJBeWkyOFk/view?usp=sharing)

- 1184 pages
- Vol. 1 begins at page # 1
- Vol. 2 begins at page # 429
- Vol. 3 begins at page # 839

I was also able to find a free copy of an **abridged** English translation of Garuda Purana by M.N. Dutt (Manmatha Nath Dutt) at two different places:

1. Google Books<sup>++</sup>: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=0Fwxjf4IM78C
2. Archive.org: https://archive.org/details/garudapuranam00duttgoog
3. Proofread HTML: http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt

   If you prefer PDF file, it's available via [this direct link](https://ia802608.us.archive.org/8/items/garudapuranam00duttgoog/garudapuranam00duttgoog.pdf) (32 MB).

<sup>++</sup> One advantage with the Google Books format is that it's searchable!

Comment: I think M.N. Dutt's translation is an abridged version.  The Motilal Banarsidass translation is a verse-by-verse translation, and I think it's much better.

Comment: Anil Kumar's answer has the Motilal Banarsidass one: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/36

Comment: Oh ok, I tried clicking on those links in the [other answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/2995) earlier and none of them seem to work. The page just times out. Maybe we should upload them to archive.org.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the DSpace site is often down.  The next time it's up I can download all three volumes and upload them to Google Drive.

Comment: Indian Scriptures too has [Garuda Purana](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran).

Comment: Uploaded  Garuda Purana to Google Drive and added it to my Answer.

Comment: @AnilKumar Thanks! But I get 'Access to the webpage was denied' message when I try to access GP from your answer.

Comment: @AnilKumar Cannot access Bhagavata Purana also. One way you could test if others can access it is by opening your answer in Chrome Incognito mode and try to download.

Comment: @sv. I can give you details of this google account in chat. I created it as repository account.

Comment: @AnilKumar Thanks for the M.B. tr. of GP. I removed all blank pages at the beginning of each volume and created a new pdf. Let me know if you want it. I was going to upload it and link it in my answer.

Comment: I don't think the version by Dutt is abridged, as the contents of chapters correspond to the translation by Motilal. It is however, written in Prose. You can find the proofread HTML of the translation by Dutt here: http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt