# What are some good books to read on life, death, afterlife, etc in Hinduism?

Tags: death, book-recommendation, afterlife

By good books, I am looking for an interpretation of scriptures that is accessible to a normal audience. Does anyone have any suggestions?

PS: Please let me know if this is out-of-scope for discussion here.

Related questions:

[English translation of complete Garuda Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/english-translation-of-complete-garuda-purana) especially [this](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt).

Other resources:

Bhagavadgita: 8. The Yoga of Imperishable Brahman

Comment: Garud puran has details on afterlife,rebirth etc

Comment: you can find Garud purana on Playstore. Good app in which whole Garud puran written will be found on playstore. I also have that app. Install and read :)