# Is there any significace of twitching of eyes?

Tags: scripture, belief, culture, superstitions, omens

Is it true that twitching of eyes indicates something?

Does it give us signal of something good or bad that is going to happen in the future?

What is the significance of left eye twitching and right eye twitching?

Is anything related to eye twitching and its significance mentioned in our scriptures?

Or can anyone give me examples from history?

Comment: I can only briefly quote that I think in Sundara Ghanda says HerSeeta's left eye twitches while Ravana's right eye twitches. I am not sure about the reference, I will try to source and provide later if possible.

Comment: I think you should just limit your question to scriptural refrences(remove  'is it true..' part it asks for opinion) on eye twitching, since discussion on superstitions is a broad and opinion based topic.

Comment: Agini Purana has Good and bad omens but it didn't mention "Eye Twitching" (Ch- 229- 233) in Volume 2. See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/3500) answer for source of Agni Purana..

Comment: yes, it is true. it is one of the many signs or omens that indicate good or bad. In Ramayana, when Rama made friendship with Sugriva, left-eye twitched for 2 people - Sita & Vali. For women, left-eye twitching is good-omen and right-eye is bad. For men, left-eye twitching is bad omen and right-eye is good. Btw, your questions seems to imply that you already decided the answer that it is a 'superstition'.

Answer (score 24):

Twitching of eyes have great significance in our scriptures. There are various description of auspicious and inauspicious omens in our scriptures and eye twitching is one of them.

Twitching of Sita's left body parts is mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana Sundara Kanda. In chapter 27 verses 48 to 50.

> निमित्तभूतमेतत्तु श्रोतुमस्या महत्प्रियम् || ५-२७-४८
>   दृश्यते च स्फुरच्चक्षुः पद्मपत्रमिवायतम् |
>
> Being a cause to listen to a great pleasure of Her, this **throbbing eye** long like a lotus petal is being seen my me.
>
> ईषच्च हृषितो वास्या दक्षिणाया ह्यदक्षिणः || ५-२७-४९
>   अकस्मादेव वैदेह्या बहुरेकः प्रकम्पते |
>
> **One left arm** of this straight forward Seetha suddenly has become erect and is slightly trembling."
>
> करेणुहस्तप्रतिमः सव्यश्चोरुरनुत्तमः || ५-२७-५०
>   वेपमानः सूचयति राघवं पुरतः स्थितम् |
>
> **Seetha's best left thigh** equal to an elephant's trunk is trembling indicating Rama's standing in front of Her.

**Valmiki Ramayana Yuddha Kanda 6.4.7** mentions it where Lord Ram tells about his twitching of eyelid.

> उपरिष्टाद्द् हि नयनम् स्फुरमाणम् इदम् मम ||
>   विजयम् समनुप्राप्तम् शंसति इव मनो रथम्  ।।
>
> "**My eye which is twitching on the upper lid, is proclaiming as it were, my desire of victory coming nearer.**"

**Valmiki Ramayana Yuddha Kanda 6.65.50** mentions bad omen signalling Kumbhakarna

> निष्पपात च गृध्रेऽस्य शूले वै पथि गच्छतः |
>   प्रास्फुरन्नयनम् चास्य सव्यो बाहुरकम्पत ||
>   
>   
>   A vulture descended on the spike of Kumbhakarna, as he was sallying forth along the road. &**His left eye twitched and his left arm throbbed.**

Similarly **Ramcharitmanas** also mentions about twitching of eye.

> Sundar kanda Ramcharitmanas Chaupai of 34th Doha
>   
>   राम कृपा बल पाइ कपिंदा । 
>   भए पच्छजुत मनहुं गिरिंदा।। 
>   हरषि राम तब कीन्ह पयाना ।
>   सगुन भए सुंदर सुभ नाना।। 
>   जासु सकल मंगलमय कीती ।
>   तासु पयान सगुन यह नीती।।
>   **प्रभु पयान जाना बैदेही ।
>
>   फरकि बाम अंग जनु कहि देहीं।।**
>   जोइ जोइ सगुन जानकिहि होई । 
>   असगुन भयउ रावनहिं सोईं।। 
>   Getting more power from His grace the monkey chiefs vied as it were with huge mountains equipped with wings.  Råma then sallied forth glad of heart 
>   and many were the delightful and auspicious omens that occurred to Him . It was in the fitness of things that good omens should appear at the time of His departure (on an expedition) whose glory itself embodies all blessings. **Videhas Daughter came to know of the Lords march; the throbbing of Her left limbs apprised Her of the same as it were.** But what were good omens for Janakas Daughter foreboded evil for Ravana.

Also, In the chaupai of 99th Doha of Ramcharitmanas

> With many such words did Trijatå comfort Sita and then returned to her residence.
>   As She recalled  Ramas kind disposition Videhas Daughter was  overwhelmed with the anguish of separation from Him. She  reproached the night and the moon in many ways. "The night has already assumed the length of an age and does not end.", She added. Disconsolate at Her separation from Lord Råma, Janakas Daughter grievously lamented within Herself. **When Her agony of separation grew acute, Her left eye and arm throbbed. Considering it to be a good omen, She took heart and said to Herself, The gracious Hero of Raghus line will surely meet me.**

Hence, twitching of right part of male and left part of female [especially eyes] is considered auspicious and vice versa.

Omen signs are greatly discussed in our scriptures. You can't tell them as mere superstition. Omens are studied under **'Shakun Shastra'**.

Every scripture mentions of omen before some important omens. For eg. Mahabharat mentions **crying of jackals and other inauspicious signs when Duryodhan was born**. Inauspicious omens were seen just after **Shishupals birth** and his parents were just about abandoning him. Similar is the case in the birth of **Kamsa**. Numerous inauspicious omens are described in great detail by Veda Vyas before the **Mahabharat war**. Similarly Ram mentions about colour of sky and stars before Ramayan war and so on many...

Hence seeing omens are a part of our scripture and culture. Hence, We should try to understand the meaning of omen we see.

Comment: Good answer with references. It would be better if you could provide links to your sources.

Comment: @Jatin refrences are from Ramcharitmanas Gita Press Book and Valmikiramayan.net

Answer (score 7):

Yes , Puranas also do talk about eye-twitching. There is a discussion mentioned in Shreemad Bhagvat purana between Yudhishthira and Bhima , **( Skanda 1 ,Chapter 14 ,Shloka 12)** --the background of which is like this.

Yudhishthira send's Arjuna to Dwaraka to make a enquiry about Shree-Krishna and to meet their relatives.But even after 7 months when Arjuna do not return. Yudhishthira then discussed this thing with Beema. He says why Arjuna not returned ,i am seeing some bad oman's.Is it time for Shree-Krishna to depart to his abode?

> This shloka gives us idea about  **left eye-twitching incident which
>   is mentioned by Yudhishthira** ,he describes this as a bad oman.
>
> ऊर्वक्षिबाहवो मह्यं स्फुरन्त्यङ्ग पुनः पुनः । 
>  वेपथुश्र्चअपि
>   ह्यदये आद्दास्यन्ति विप्रियम् ॥11॥
>
> ūrv-akṣi-bāhavo mahyaṁ  sphuranty aṅga punaḥ punaḥ 
>  vepathuś cāpi
>   hṛdaye ārād dāsyanti vipriyam
>
> **Meaning** - The left side of my body — my thighs, arms and eyes — are all quivering again and again. I am having heart palpitations due
>   to fear. All this indicates undesirable happenings. [**SB
>   1.14.11**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/14/11)

---

Here is the commentary by Swami Prabhupada :-
When a man’s left eye, arm and thigh all quiver constantly, one must know that something is going to happen which is undesirable.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, twitching of left eye means something desirable is about to happen.

[Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/53/27) is one example from Srimad Bhagavatam in which Rukmini's left eye twitches when Lord Krishna was arriving in her palace.

> evaṁ vadhvāḥ pratīkṣantyā govindāgamanaṁ nṛpa
>   
> vāma ūrur bhujo netram asphuran priya-bhāṣiṇaḥ (SB - 10.53.27)
>   
>  Meaning: O King, as the bride thus awaited the arrival of Govinda, she felt a twitch in her left thigh, arm and eye. This was a sign that something desirable would happen

Comment: Also, just one twitch not *continuous* twitching.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of the Eye Twisting astrology followed in India

In India, the superstition of eye twitching is reverse to the Chinese. Also, the eye twitching superstition in India is based on the eye that twitches, gender and the part of the eye that twitches.

In terms of the eye twitching, a twitch of the right eye is usually a good sign. It could mean that you will receive positive news, make money or be successful in some way. Unfortunately, twitching of the left eye is a bad omen.

Gender also dictates the meaning of twitching. Twitching on a woman's left eye is a good sign whereas it is a bad one for a man.

There are about five superstitions in India that are related to the part of the eye that twitches. Left eye pupil twitching is a sign of good luck, middle eye twitching signals money related gains, left eyelid shows that someone is about to undergo some worrying moments, if the lower part of the left eye twitches then you will be spending some money soon, and if the left eyebrow twitches then a child is about to be born and you will receive some positive news as well.

[Source](http://www.newhealthadvisor.com/Eye-Twitching-Superstition.html)

Comment: Where are the sources bro?