# What scriptures say about left arm twitching / quivering / throbbing?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, omens

What scriptures say about left arm twitching?

Some sites say it is a good indication, whereas some say it is good for ladies only and not good for men.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11005/is-there-any-significace-of-twitching-of-eyes/11055#11055

Comment: which site says it's a good indication ? does that site also mention the gender for which it is a good omen ? for women - left eye/hand twitch is good. for men - right is good. for women - right is bad. for men - left is bad. did your left eye also twitch ?

Comment: The book `Secrets Of Occult Science - L. R. Chawdhri` says so. No, it doesnt mention about gender. Also, i found many online sites that say so. for example this site:
http://www.astroshastra.info/BlogDet.php?id=73
No, no twitching in my eyes. Generally, when my left arm used to twitch, it indicated some disputes with someone. I dont know if there is some other meanings of that.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the case of Rukmini when she actually found her lost son, Pradyumna. It is a good sign for ladies.

A few verses from Srimad Bhagavatam mention about such signs.

> [SB 10.55.34](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/55/34) - Yes, He must be the same child I bore in my womb, since I feel great affection for Him and my left arm is quivering.

The below is case with Yudhisthira, it indicates inauspiciousness for males.

> [SB 1.14.11](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/14/11) - The left side of my body — my thighs, arms and eyes — are all quivering again and again. I am having heart palpitations due to fear. All this indicates undesirable happenings.

Comment: Dear downvoters, what's the reason ?

Comment: Perhaps you answered personal advice off topic question from scripture

Comment: @AkshayS even if it is the case, why downvote the answer, only downvoting and closevoting the question would have been sufficient.

Comment: It happens.  Leave it

Comment: This is not a off topic Q and personal advice parts if any can easily be removed by any one of us... @AkshayS

Comment: @Rickross You are correct. That's why I didnt vote to close... But I said the reason for downvotes could be answering off topic questions as per those particular users.