# Which chapter of Skanda Purana contains Guru Gita?

Tags: skanda-purana

Everyone is aware that Guru Gita is considered to be taken from Uttara Khanda of Skanda Puranam. But I cannot find in the links provided [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas). Is there any other version of Skanda Purana uttara Khanda which contains guru gita available online/offline with sanskrit text and translation? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the Skanda Purana in the University library here, having the same question as yours. There is no Uttara Khanda in it, except for a section in the Brahma Khanda of that name but having no Guru Gita. There is no Guru Gita text in the Skanda Purana, but maybe there was an ancient version of it that did which is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the Guru Gita (full 400 verses version) in the Skanda Purana where it is supposed to be..but could not found it anywhere !
Anyway thanks for the link to the detailed contents of each book !
I wonder where Swami Muktananda and other spiritual leaders got the 182 main verses widely used all over the world ...

Comment: Guru gita in this site is not OCRable
https://archive.org/details/GuruGitaInSkandaPurana1077GhaAlm5Shlf4DevanagariPurana/page/n13/mode/2up
By the endeavour of Sri PR Ramachander, http://stotrarathna.blogspot.com/2020/01/guru-gita-song-of-guru.html?m=1. (contain 274 verses) .<br/>Kanchi Kamakoti official site also hosts SriGuruGita https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotra/SriGuruGita.html