# Can someone provide non-ISKCON online resources for Krishna-related scriptures?

Tags: krishna, resource, iskcon

If you search for something like Bhagavatam, you get overwhelmed by "supreme personality of godhead" type material.

Comment: Strongly related: [Are there non-ISKCONic translations of the Bhagavata Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16094/277)

Comment: @ram Let's discuss in moderation room. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/moderation

Answer (score 5):

For translations other than ISKCON, you may [try this translation of the Bhāgavata Purāṇa](https://archive.org/download/BhagavataPuranaWithEnglishTranslationGitaPress/Bhagavata%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation%20Gita%20Press.pdf) and [this translation of the Bhagavadgītā](http://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Bhagavad-Gita-Translation-by-Shri-Purohit-Swami.pdf).

For the Chaitanyacharitāmṛta, you cannot get any online resources. However, you can get a non-ISKCONic translation as a hardcopy [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674002857).

Comment: If it is a gaudiya source (of "Brahma Samhita" fame) Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: None of them are Gaudiya translations but neutral ones. However, the Chaitanya Charitamrita is followed by Gaudiyas only. @SK

Answer (score 1):

https://www.archive.org is a good source for the transliteration of Srimad Bhagavatam published by Motilal Banarasidass & Gita Press.