# Where can I get the complete English translations of the Upapuranas?

Tags: translation-request, upapuranas

Though it is easy to find the translations of all the 18 major Puranas in English, I haven't still found the complete English translations of the Upapuranas. So where can I find the complete English translations of the upapuranas specifically of the following:

- Vishnudharma Purana
- Vishnudharmottara Purana
- Narasimha Purana
- Kriyayogasara Purana
- Mudgala Purana
- Ganesha Purana
- Bhavishyottara Purana (not to be confused with Bhavishya Purana)
- Kapila Purana
- Saura Purana
- Samba Purana
- Brihannaradiya Purana
- Brihaddharma Purana

Comment: Please tell me where you find all of the 18 Puranas online?

Comment: There are many websites. Names of some of the websites can be found in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas?rq=1

Comment: I am searching mainly for Bhavishya Purana and Brahma Purana (readable online, not like website you posted)

Comment: Also Harivamsa Purana too.

Comment: You can find major puranas on [vedpuran.com](http://vedpuran.com)

Comment: If comfortable with Hindi - Saura Purana can be read [from here at archive](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.406611/page/n1/mode/2up)

Answer (score 3):

English translation of [Viṣṇudharmottara Purāṇa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnudharmottara_Purana) (Kāṇḍa III) is available at archive.org:

- [Shri Vishnudharmottara (A Text on Ancient Indian Arts), Priyabala Shah](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.127780)
- [The Vishnudharmottara Part III: A Treatise On Indian Painting And Image-Making, Stella Kramrisch](https://archive.org/stream/vishnudharmottar031493mbp#page/n7/mode/2up)

The full 3-volume translation (by Priyabala Shah) that includes Kāṇḍas I & II is available for sale at [Exotic India](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/visnudharmottara-purana-3-volumes-IDF396/).

English Translation of [Narasimha Purāṇa](https://archive.org/stream/NarasimhaPuranaWithEnglishTranslation/Narasimha%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation#page/n0/mode/1up])
 along with Sanskrit text is available on archive.org

Comment: Do you mind if I add narsimha purana too? It is also available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/NarasimhaPuranaWithEnglishTranslation/Narasimha%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation#page/n0/mode/1up).

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

- [Kalki Purana with Sanskrit Verse (in English) and English translation](http://om-aditya.ru/userfiles/ufiles/purany/sri_kalki_purana.pdf)
- [Narasimha Purana with Sanskrit Verse (in Devnagari) and English translation](https://archive.org/stream/NarasimhaPuranaWithEnglishTranslation/Narasimha%20Purana%20with%20English%20Translation#page/n0/mode/1up)

---

[Most of the Upapuranas (**in Sanskrit Only**)](https://archive.org/details/Upapurana)