# Where can i get original versions of the Devi Bhagavata and Markandeya Puranas?

Tags: puranas, durga, devi-bhagavata-purana, markandeya-purana

I am looking for the original version of the [Devi Bhagavata Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi-Bhagavata_Purana) and (or) other Puranas which has lots of information about Devi Durga.

I have the short version of it but it does not have anything about mata Durga. That is more like a Bhagvata Gita.

I also want [the Markandeya Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markandeya_Purana) in its original version. Anybody knows from where to get them?

Comment: You want them in Sanskrit, English or in any other languages?

Comment: BTW Devi Bhagavat and Markandey Purana are two different Purana. Marakandeya Purana contains Devi Mahatmya.

Answer (score 7):

**Markandeya Purana;**

[Here](http://www.pushpak.de/markandeya/markandeya_en.pdf) is Markandeya Purana unabridged in English.

[And from here](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/2/items/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi.pdf) you can get it in Sanskrit-Hindi (Sanskrit original slokas with their Hindi translations).

**Devi Bhagavatam**

From [this page](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatamindex.htm) you can read it in unabridged English translated by Swami Vijñanananda.

**Some other Puranas that have information on Goddess Durga.**

As is well known Durga Puja is quite famous in Bengal. And here they follow mainly four Puranas for the worship procedures apart from following the Agama scriptures. And, they are:

1) Devi Bhagavata 2) Markandeya Purana 3) Kalika Purana and 4) Brinnandikeswara Purana.

Of which , the last two are considered as upapurans. So, apart from the Markandeya Purana and the Devi Bhagavatam, the two upapuranas i mentioned also contain a lot of information on Devi Durga but i think it is hard to find them online.

Answer (score 6):

You can get unabridged Devi Bhagavata Purana and Markandeya Purana in Sanskrit and English with verse by verse translation from [IndianScriptures site](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/). Here are links for them.

- [Devibhagavata Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/upa-purana/srimad-devibhagavatam)
- [Markandeya Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/markandeya-purana)

Each Chapter is uploaded as separate pdf file on that site.

You can also read **Lalita Mahatmya** of Brahmanda Purana which describes glory of Mother Lalita.  You can get Brahmanda Purana in English from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/3500).

You can also visit below question for more resources.

[What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/3500)

Comment: @SreeCharan I didn't get you. I have read multiple times the sentence, "glory of the divine Mother".

Comment: It was a phrase from your sentence "You can also read Devi Mahatmya of Brahmanda Purana which describes glory of Mother Lalita." In this sentence, you mentioned mother before Lalita. Were you looking for a feminine word for Lord?

Comment: @SreeCharan It would be Lady and that sounds bad. Mother is good.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Divine Mother, Mother Goddess are common. Don't know what the problem is this time??

Comment: @TheDestroyer What do you mean by "Devi Mahatmya of Brahmanda Purana"? The Devi Mahatmya belongs to the Markandeya Purana, the Lalita Mahatmya belongs to the Brahmanda Purana.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks! I fixed it. i was thinking of Markandeya Purana when writing that sentence.

Comment: @TheDestroyer There is no Lalita Mahatya either. Its "lalitopakhyana". in Brahmanda Purana.

Comment: @Rickross I think it is also called as Lalita Mahatmya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer You're welcome.  By the way, I've been to the place where Vishnu's incarnation Hayagriva told the Lalita Mahatmya to the sage Agastya.  It's near Kumbakonam in Tamil Nadu, there's a Lalita temple in that spot now.  I was excited to go there, since it was a place where Hayagriva had personally visited, but they didn't even have a Hayagriva statue.  So I ended up just bowing to the ground, since it's ground that Hayagriva walked on.

Comment: @TheDestroyer So the Lalitopakhyana is the same as Lalita Mahatmya? Or are they distinct portions of the same Purana?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, the Lalitopakhyana and the Lalita Mahatmya refer to the same portion of the Brahmanda Purana.

Answer (score 3):

Gita Press Gorakhpur is an online site that offers books on Indian Religion and Mythology at unbelievable prices. You should check that out.