# Who are some great devotees of Lord Ganesha from the scriptures?

Tags: scripture, ganesha, bhakti

I am looking for the names of some Lord Ganesha devotees.Those names have to be mentioned in the scriptures.

In scriptures (like the PurAnas) we often find such names. For example, PrahlAda was a great devotee of Lord Vishnu, Dadichi, MArkendeya that of Lord Shiva ( MArkandeya was also a devotee of Lord Vishnu i think) etc.

Comment: Amazing question. Bravo :) - a Saint from recent times. Although you are asking from mythology point of view. just for info.- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morya_Gosavi

Comment: Also Raavana of Shiva

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks and yes i am looking only for characters who are mentioned in scriptures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ganesha Purana and some Ganesha-centric scriptures mention few great devotees of Sri Ganesha.

Since i don't have complete Ganesha Purana, i will cite **[Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/details/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft) by Vettam mani** as reference. I will update exact references as soon as possible.

Here are some list of devotees:

1. Ballala was a son of Vaishya and Lord Ganesha Himself manifests at his worship place pleased by his devotion.

   > **Ballala**: Son of a Vaisya named Kalyana. From childhood Ballala was an ardent devotee of Ganapati.  When he was a child he used to gather
   >   pebbles and  make a heap and then worship it, imagining it to be
   >   GaneSa (Ganapati).
   >
   > His parents did not like this. They tried their best to dissuade him
   >   from this habit. Once they tied him to a tree and gave him severe
   >   cuts. But their attempts  were futile. One day an image of Ganapati
   >   arose in  the place where the child used to worship. **(GaneSa Purana
   >   1 : 2)**.
2. There was fisherman named Brusundi who was evil and at a suggestion of sage, he did  sever tapasya on Ganesha and he developed a trunk like Ganesha.

   > **Bhrusundi**. A fisherman. He used to earn his living  by theft.
   >
   > Once when the Maharsi Mudgala was passing through a forest , Bhrsundi
   >   stopped him. But in the presence of the Brahmanic effulgence of the
   >   Maharsi, the fisherman was dazed. Mudgala took pity on Bhrsundi and
   >   advised him to worship Lord Ganesa.
   >
   > From that time Bhrsundi gave up his evil ways, and accepting the
   >   advice of Mudgala, started the worship of Ganesa with single-minded
   >   devotion. As a result of it, an elephant's trunk began to grow from
   >   the middle of his forehead. Bhrsundi who thus acquired a shape closely
   >   resembling Ganesa, was visited by Indra, mistaking him for Ganapati.
   >   **(Ganesa : 1.67)**.
3. There's story of another devotee of Ganesha called **Mankana** which is bit surprising. Shiva decides to burn his favorite city Kasi  and Ganesha helps in that ploy. Maybe we can know exact context when we read complete chapter or preceding chapters. Puranic encyclopedia gives Vayu Purana and Brahmanda Purana references which i couldn't verify with [Motilal editions of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/3500).

   > **MANKANA**: A barber of VaranasI  who was a great devotee of Ganesa. During the time of  King Divodasa. Siva wanted to destroy the city
   >   of  KasI and deputed his son Ganesa (Nikumbha) for the  same.
   >
   > Ganesa came to Kasi and appearing in person before  his devotee
   >   Mankana, asked him to build a temple on  the outskirts of Kasi. Mankana
   >   completed the temple  and Ganesa (Nikumbha) installed himself in that 
   >   temple getting for it the name Nikumbhamandira.  Devotees began to
   >   flow into the temple and Nikumbha  sitting there answered the prayers
   >   of all. But he never  fulfilled the prayer of the King to have a son.
   >   This  annoyed Divodasa and he destroyed the temple and  then Nikumbha
   >   cursed that the city of Kasi would  become desolate. Siva's desire
   >   thus became fulfilled.  **(92. 33, Vayu Purana and 3; 67, 43. Brahmanda 
   >   Purana)**.

Comment: This is quite a good answer in fact . So, i am selecting it. You can update it later. If i get more answers then i will think.

Comment: @Rickross Ok. i will try to update and if you get other better answer, feel free to select that answer.