# Where can I get the Bhavishya Purana in PDF format?

Tags: puranas, resource, bhavishya-purana

Please tell me from where I can purchase the Bhavishya Purana in PDF format so that I can read it on my iPad or laptop. I have a copy of this text but it isn't readable due to scanned pages of the printed book.

Comment: Closer: [Complete English translation of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9078/277).

Comment: Your URL Doesn't contain required Purana.

Answer (score 6):

You can get Bhavishya Purana in pdf at following sources:

- Bhavishya Purana in hindi at [vedpuran.net](https://vedpuran.net/download-all-ved-and-puran-pdf-hindi-free/)
- In English : [IndianDivine.org](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/197-all-18-maha-puranas-in-english-pdf/)
  (In English all 18 Purans are there in pdf; scroll down to check-list Bhavishya Purana.)
- Bhavishya Purana (Bhavishya Maha Purana) -Pratisarg Parv -Khand Three full translated to English [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/AlhaKhandInBhavishyaPuranaRevisedAndRechekedPart11)

Also take a look for online reading at  [Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bhavishyapurana.htm) and at [Hindu Online](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/BhavishyaPurana.html).

Comment: "Click here" type of links should be avoided. [Why shouldn't we use words such as 'here' and 'this' in textlinks?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/12100)

Comment: @Fierce: I don't know English, I need in Hindi.

Comment: @Manoj Pilania the first link that i given(hindi one) when you click it there in starting will be a downloadable list of 18 puranas there is **bhavishya purana in hindi** my dear friend.

Comment: vedpuran.net mostly reproduce things from Internet Archive or from other place. e.g. [Bhavishya Purana at Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/BhavishyaPurana).

Comment: @Pandya we have to take the book then either from ved puran.net or internet archieve :)

Comment: @Fiercelord Yes, what I want to tell is Internet Archive link is better than blog.