# Where we can get unabridged puranas?

Tags: puranas

Where can we get unabridged version of puranas, uppuranas in Sanskrit - Hindi Translation with some commentary in PDF format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind)

Comment: @YDS I already readed your possible duplicate but it's not duplicate because I want unabridged Puranas in Sanskrit Hindi Translation.

Comment: it has other Q as well **Where can I find the Hindu scriptures in Sanskrit with Hindi rendition/translation?** in its body...

Comment: @Hayagreev Ram It isn't possible Duplicate.

Comment: @user17854 I think this is a dup. of [Complete English translations of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas).