# Reading books on Puranas

Tags: puranas

I am planning to read Puranas. I would like to make a start and continue. Can you recommend where to start and also a book (only in English) please. I am interested in a hardback book only.
Thanks

Comment: "I am interested in a hardback book only" - from the first few pages of the soft copies of Puranas, you can easily find who the publisher is and either directly purchase from them or a reseller like [Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Motilal+Banarsidass+Publishers+Puranas&ref=nb_sb_noss) or [Exotic India Art](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/find.php?searchval2=purana&table2=all&archives2=&subcatsearch2=all&specialcriteria=mustorcat%7Cbook%3A4%7Csculptures%3A4&searchmodifier2=allwords&limitfields2=all&materialsearch2=all&minprice2=&maxprice2=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALL 18 MAJOR PURANAS** by **IGS** (International Gita Society) contains abridged version of 18 puranas in 884 pages.

This can be found in PDF format:

- on their [official website](https://gita-society.com/scriptures/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS.pdf) (seems to be unavailable right now)
- [Archive](https://archive.org/details/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS_201803).

Web format:

- [gloriousindia](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/index.php)

---

After reading this, you can start reading the full version of the Purana which you like. The source of full versions can be found in below post(s):

[Complete English translations of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas)

[What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind)

Comment: "All 18 Major Puranas" is this available as a book from IGS or somewhere else?

Comment: @Leprechaun not sure about hard copy...i read in pdf from IGS..