# Is there any sukta in Rigveda containing 16 richas and starting with the word"Indra"?

Tags: vedas, mantras, rig-veda, indra, agni-purana

There is a chapter called Rigvidhana in Agnipurana in which it is mentioned that if the aforementioned 16 Richas are chanted daily then one is blessed with intelligence, friends and fulfillment of desires.

So, the question is - Is there any sukta in Rigveda containing 16 richas and starting with the word "Indra"?

Comment: There might be Hymns available such as one starting with - इन्द्रो मदाय वाव्र्धे (R V 1.81). And, may contain 16 mantras.  However,  as far as I know,  they are for spiritual knowledge ONLY but not any material benefits.   Where did you read it.? Please quote reference.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, You are looking for Rigveda 1.32.1

The verse of Agnipurana you're talking about in the question might be ***Agnipurana 259.14*** (259<sup>th</sup> chapter from Agnipurna is "Rigvidhanam") quoting from [sa.wikisource.org](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%AB%E0%A5%AF): (Transliterated into IAST):

> **ṛgbhiḥ ṣoḍaśabhiḥ** kuryyād**indra**syeti dine dine |
> hihaṇyastūpamityetajjapan śatrūn prabādhate || 259.14 ||

After locating this verse from Sanskrit Wikisource, I've tried reading translation of this verse from [a book on English translation of Agnupurana](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B0XpAgOLu_nHelp2dm9mdkVIOW8&export=download) from West Bengal Dspace as provided by 'The Destroyer' in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/277) and here is what I find: (Page no. 730)

> [image]

As you can see, in the notes, they're giving the link of this Agnipurana's saying to Rigveda hymns : Rigveda 1.32.1

So, what you are looking is **32<sup>nd</sup> Sukta of 1<sup>st</sup> Mandala of Rigveda**

- The Sukta starts as (You can read Sanskrit text from [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/sanskrit03/RV0301noaccent.html) and Egnlish translation from [sacred-texts.com](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01032.htm)):

  > Indrasya nu vīryāṇi pra vocaṃ yāni cakāra prathamāni vajrī|
  > Ahannahimanvapastatarda pra vakṣaṇā abhinatparvatānām|| 1.032.01

Comment: OP had mentioned that (1) there should be 16 Rochas and (2) if the aforementioned 16 Richas are chanted daily then one is blessed with intelligence, friends and fulfillment of desires. RV 1.32 contains 15 only. Please check