# Are there any English puranic storybooks ? Specific purana or multiple both will do

Tags: puranas, gods

I am looking for Puranic storybooks in english.
Can be one specific purana or stories from many puranas.

Comment: Are you looking for English translations of Puranas such as the ones mentioned in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas) or simply a collection of concise stories from various Puranas?

Comment: As you rightly pointed ,I am looking for collection of concise stories not translations

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the puranas and other books in condensed/story format:

- [Srimad Bhagavatam Condensed](https://www.amazon.in/Srimad-Bhagavatam-Condensed-Purnaprajna-Dasa/dp/B00QIPIHYC)
- [Stories from Puranas](https://www.amazon.in/Stories-Puranas-Purnaprajna-Dasa/dp/8192540847)
- [Sri Brahma Vaivarta Purana](https://www.amazon.in/BRAHMA-VAIVARTA-PURANA-PURNAPRAJNA-DASA/dp/8184030711)
- [Sri Narada Purana](https://www.amazon.in/SRI-NARADA-PURANA-PURNAPRAJNA-DASA/dp/8187812753)
- [Sri Padma Purana](https://www.amazon.in/Padma-Purana-Srila-Dvaidayana-Vedavyasa/dp/8187812583)
- [Sri Skanda Purana](https://www.amazon.in/SKANDA-PURANA-PURNAPRAJNA-DASA)
- [Sri Shiva Purana](https://www.amazon.in/Shiva-Purana-English-Dreamland-Publications-ebook/dp/B0746GXHPF/)

Also there are quite a number of translations available for various puranas in English, some are:

- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/) online, this is a commentary may be you can just go through the translations.
- [Garuda Purana](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1)

Will update more. And there are also other puranic story books to purchase from [Gitapress Gorakhpur](https://www.gitapress.org/) with or without sanskrit texts.

Comment: He's looking for a collection of concise stories from various Puranas. Not verse-by-verse or word-for-word English translations.

Comment: @sv. Thanks for clarifying. Have updated my answer. I did gave the link to gitapress which has not only translations but also condensed version of puranas with the stories. Sorry if it was not clear and for not being specific.