# word-for-word translation of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam śloka 5.12.11

Tags: translation-request

I need to know word-for-word translation in the following Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam śloka 5.12.11;
jñānaṁ viśuddhaṁ paramārtham ekam anantaraṁ tv abahir brahma satyam
Someone Pandit,please help me.

Comment: Pure translation questions can be off topic here. Visit [this Meta discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1676/277) to know how to frame the question properly.  You can find word for word translation of Bhagavata Purana at [Vedabase](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/2/11/). Also check [this existing Q](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9078/277)

Comment: Most of the words are pretty simple. Couldn't you translate it yourself?

Comment: Dear Pandya and Aupakarana Abhibhaa, it seems that my poor English do not convey what I mean.  I don't know how to say. How about I need not idiomatic translation but literal translation of upper portion of the silokas. I know synonyms and  translation by Srila Prabhupada. I can guess the upper portion part of the siloka from synonyms and translation. But that will vague. I need grammatically correct translation of just only upper part of the siloka for my report. I do not have any Sanskrit experts around me.

Answer (score 1):

The word-to-word translation of entire shrimadbhagwatam can be found [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/)

The word to word translation of the specific shloka  [5.12.11](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/12/11/) is

> jñānam — the supreme knowledge; viśuddham — without contamination; parama-artham — giving the ultimate goal of life; ekam — unified; anantaram — without interior, unbroken;

Comment: Dear Panibotal, thank you for your concern.But I know this word meaning, synonyms by Srila Prabhupada.Thanks anyway.